# Inject aspx forms and functionality with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, modal-dialog

Can you inject aspx forms along with their functionality into a div using the jQuery ajax load method. I am essentially trying to create a modal popup that allows me to load remote web forms into the popup and have the user use the form and submit.I have the modal built and it transitions in perfectly, however it isn't worth it to use if there is no functionality( i.e. I want the code behind of that page to be injected along with it).

Thanks,

-Seth

Answer (score 1):

jQuery aside - making an AJAX request for any page will merely load the HTML generated by the web server. The corresponding page could be generated by any type of script that's supported by the server: PHP, ASP, whatever.

Comment: Thanks,that actually put it in perspective and everything I wanted to do works now.